# Como faço para listar todos os controllers instanciáveis no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No Laravel 5, temos uma pasta chamada `Http\Controllers` que tem os controllers usados na aplicação.

Lá também há um controller chamado `Controller`, que é abstrato, ou seja, é usado apenas para ser estendido por outros controllers. Em alguns casos, eu também costumo criar meu próprio Controller abstrato, para poder estender funcionalidades em outros Controllers.

Exemplo:

```
  app/
    Http
       /Controllers
          Controller.php #abstrato
          Webservice/
               AbstractController.php #abstrato
               ServerController.php
               ClienteController.php

          PageController.php
          UsuariosController.php
```

Gostaria, de alguma maneira, listar esses controllers (exceto os que não são instanciáveis), e salvá-los em um `array`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Preciso que eles fiquem assim:

```
[ 
  'Webservice/ServerController', 
  'Webservice/ClienteController', 
  'PageController',
  'UsuariosController'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um [Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan), escrevendo um [Command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands). É simples fazer essa geração de valores dos Controllers.

Coloque esse Command na sua aplicação Laravel, dentro da pasta `app\Commands`:

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ListControllers extends Command  {

    protected $name = 'controllers:list';
    protected $description = 'List of Controllers';
    protected $signature = 'controllers:list';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->comment('');
        $this->comment(' List Controllers');
        $this->comment('*------------------------------------------------------*');
        $this->comment('');

        $array = $this->listControllers();

        $this->save($array);

        $this->comment('');
        $this->comment('*------------------------------------------------------*');
    }
    protected  function listControllers($view = true)
    {
        $path = app_path('Http/Controllers');
        $namespaceControllers = '\App\Http\Controllers';
        $dir = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
        foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $filename => $file)        {
            if ($file->isFile() && $filename != '.' && $filename != '..')
            {
                $filename = str_replace($path, '', $filename);
                if ((new \ReflectionClass($namespaceControllers.str_replace('.php','', $filename)))->isInstantiable())
                {
                    $array[] = substr(str_replace('.php', '', $filename), 1);
                    if ($view)
                    {
                        $this->comment(substr(str_replace('.php', '', $filename), 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
    protected function save(array $array = array(), $path = "files.php")
    {
        if (file_exists($path))
        {
            unlink($path);
        }
        $fp = fopen($path, "a+");
        fwrite($fp, "['");
        fwrite($fp, implode("','",$array));
        fwrite($fp, "']");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Para que funcione no `php artisan` entre no arquivo `app\Console\Kernel.php` e adicione mais uma linha na variável `$commands` ***'App\Commands\ListControllers'***:

```
protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
        'App\Commands\ListControllers',
    ];
```

Após a adição e a configuração, vai no prompt de comando ou correlativo e faça:

```
php artisan controller:list
```

Na tela vai mostrar uma saída de todos os controllers instanciaveis e na mesma pasta local do Laravel um arquivo com o nome de **files.php** que tem o *layout* em `array` dos `Controllers`

Comment: Obrigado, João, pela contribuição. Achei que eu teria que responder essa, mas enfim encontrei um Artisan aqui no Stackoverlow +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, por nada!